# Why is my JSON not transferred correctly from clientside to serverside

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "fields":[
    {"name":"thom","techname":"rgom","description":"dfgkjd","type":"text"},
    {"name":"thom","techname":"rgom2","description":"dfgkjd","type":"text"}
   ]
}
```

When I post it to a NodeJS-server using this code:

```
    $.ajax({ 
      data : data, 
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      timeout: 10000,         
      url : '/schema/create', 
      success : function(response) {
        console.log(response)
      },
      complete : function() {
      },
      error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
          alert("Timeout");
        } else {
          alert("Der opstod følgende fejl:" + t + x + m + ". Kontakt COWI");
        }
      }

    });
```

And insert it:

```
db.collection('schemas').insert(fields, {upsert:true}, function(err, result) {
  if(!err){
    console.log("written");
    console.log(result);

  }
});
```

In MongoDB I have:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5512ed12ecacf6e01da7aaa4"),
"fields[0][name]" : "thom",
"fields[0][techname]" : "rgom",
"fields[0][description]" : "dfgkjd",
"fields[0][type]" : "text",
"fields[1][name]" : "thom",
"fields[1][techname]" : "rgom2",
"fields[1][description]" : "dfgkjd",
"fields[1][type]" : "text"
```

I was expecting:

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("5512ed12ecacf6e01da7aaa4"),
  "fields":
  [
    {
      "name":"thom", 
      "techname" : "rgom",
      "description" : "dfgkjd",
      "type" : "text"
    },
    {
      "name":"thom", 
      "techname" : "rgom2",
      "description" : "dfgkjd",
      "type" : "text"
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT:**
Logged before insert:

```
[ { 'fields[0][name]': 'thom',
    'fields[0][techname]': 'rgom',
    'fields[0][description]': 'dfgkjd',
    'fields[0][type]': 'text',
    'fields[1][name]': 'thom',
    'fields[1][techname]': 'rgom2',
    'fields[1][description]': 'dfgkjd',
    'fields[1][type]': 'text',
    _id: 5512ed12ecacf6e01da7aaa4 } ]
```

**EDIT 2**
Console logged before insert (using JSON.stringify()):

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5512f0d4606391f41ddd16d1"),
        "{"fields":[{"name":"sdkljg","techname":"fgklj","description":"dfgklj","
type":"text"}]}" : ""
}
```

Comment: the two look equivalent, just logged differently. where are you getting the "fields[n][field_name]" type output from

Comment: db.schemas.find().pretty() in the mongo-console - I don't think they look equivalent - as "fields[1][description]" is quoted and therefore a name.

Comment: `console.log(fields)` before the insert statement.

Comment: Also, on the client side, what is `data`? an object, or a string.

Comment: On the client side data is an object

Comment: There's at least half your problem. If you want to post json, post json, not an object. Otherwise you will have to take the post params and turn it back into an object before inserting into mongodb.

Comment: @Bildsoe what do you mean it's 'quoted and therefore a name'? it's a string...

Comment: @jtmarmon - thats what i meant, sorry.

Comment: @KevinB - will JSON.stringify() suffice?

Comment: Yes, that will be enough. Though, it would be wise to also have `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: @KevinB maybe it's just me but it looks like there's no issue inserting it into the db here, just in how it's logged..

Comment: Correct, the problem has nothing to do with mongodb. It's in how he's sending the data client side and accepting it server-side.

Comment: @KevinB - i tried querying it after insert, and it doesn't work - also after JSON.stringify() - the complete json-string is the name of the property...

Comment: Then you aren't accepting the json data properly with node. What modules are you using server-side? expressjs?

Comment: @KevinB -  contentType: 'application/json' did the difference, it works now. Will you create an answer. I'm using formidable.js to receive data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format that you got when you logged `fields` before the db insert indicates that you sent the data as form params from the client to the server. If doing that, you would have to manually convert it back into an object to insert into mongodb. It would be much easier if you instead just sent it as a json string so that you wouldn't have to transform it server-side.

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
contentType: 'application/json'
```